# Schedule notifications in android

Tags: android, kotlin, notifications

I have an android app to schedule notifications at a specific times like

```
["19:00","2:00","13:00"]
```

Currently i'm using `AlarmManager` , i read about `job scheduler` and `work manager`

Questions : What is the best one to efficiently let the user receive the notification in time as `AlarmManager` doesn't give a notification in most cases

Comment: `AlarmManager` not working is obviously not intended behaviour, so maybe try and fix that instead of switching over to something else?

Answer (score -1):

The best way to use Alarm manager, job scheduler or other long-running components is to use work manager because it is the one-stop for all these things:

How to make scheduled notification with work manager: https://medium.com/android-ideas/scheduling-notifications-on-android-with-workmanager-6d84b7f64613

[image]

source: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager?gclsrc=aw.ds&&gclid=CjwKCAjwm7mEBhBsEiwA_of-TEMHDJjY8VlUTH6MMt1sOW7l_CuO2jv-B2hSu5VQ-5jbrIEXhaSbuRoCr5sQAvD_BwE